# maximal compact topology

Tags: general-topology, compactness

We know that every compact KC spaces are maximal compact.

**( 1) : Is  each compact topology contained in a compact  KC topology? ( that is , is  contained in a maximal compact topology)**

(2) : **A countable KC space has no non- trivial convergent sequence iff every compact subspace is finite.?**

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes; this is Remark $1$ of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306082v1).
2. Yes; this is Corollary $4$ of Ofelia T. Alas & Richard G. Wilson, ‘Spaces in which compact subsets are closed and the lattice of $T_1$ topologies on a set’, *Comment. Math. Univ. Carolinae* $43,4$ $(2002)$, $641$-$652$.

Comment: The cited paper in answer 1 show attempts towards an answer for question 1. The authors show (among others) that compact topologies are contained in a compact US-topology and moreover that sequentially compact topologies are contained in a maximal sequentially compact topology. A positive answer to question 1 is given by Kovár, "On Maximality of Compact Topologies" (2005), Theorem 2 (http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2005/118/).